# Linear combination of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real number. We know that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac13 x_n-2x_{n+1}$ is convergent.

My question is as follows. Suppose that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac13 x_n-2x_{n+1}$ converges. Can we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is convergent?

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the partial sums.
\begin{eqnarray}
T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3} x_k-2x_{k+1}&=&\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k-x_{k+1}-\frac{5}{3}\sum_{k=1}^nx_{k+1}
\\&=&\frac{1}{3}(x_1-x_{n+1})-\frac{5}{3}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x_{k}.
\end{eqnarray}
We know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n= 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n= T$, since given series is convergent. Then taking the limit of both sides  we get $\sum x_k$ is convergent.

Comment: I think you have to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n}$ also exists, which is not much hard.

Comment: in fact ı leave it to tes tes, since it is not much hard.